# Why viewmodel modelstate validates navigation property of an entity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, navigation-properties

I have a problem with simple validation during controller Create action for entity ARTICLE. I am using EF 4 database first. Entity ARTICLE is used as foreign key in entity ACTION(ACTION.ARTICLE_id). That's why code generation tool add navigation property to entity ARTICLE, even it does not make not much sense. Each time I update entities the clasess gets to form below(ARTICLE). I checked all foreign key many times again. I really dont know what to do with this error to make clean soluton, not just clearing error in controller action. Everything - even view are scaffolded.

Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "ARTICLE_ADMIN")]
    public ActionResult Edit(ARTICLE article)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            article.date_modified = DateTime.Now;

            string newimage = this.Request.Form["preview_image_filename"];
            string oldimage = this.Request.Form["original_image_filename"];

            if (newimage.NotNullOrEmpty())
            {
                article.preview_image = newimage;
            }
            else
            {
                article.preview_image = oldimage;
            }

            db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        article.date_modified = DateTime.Now;

        ViewBag.ARTICLE_CATEGORY_id = new SelectList(db.ARTICLE_CATEGORY, "ARTICLE_CATEGORY_id", "description", article.ARTICLE_CATEGORY_id);
        ViewBag.ARTICLE_STATUS_id = new SelectList(db.ARTICLE_STATUS, "ARTICLE_STATUS_id", "description", article.ARTICLE_STATUS_id);
        ViewBag.WEB_USER_id = new SelectList(db.WEB_USER, "WEB_USER_id", "login", article.WEB_USER_id);
        return View(article);
    }
```

I am using this entity model generated via code generation tool with added annotations in metadata class, it cant be more simple

```
public partial class ARTICLE
{
    public ARTICLE()
    {
        this.PROGRAM_WEEK_DAY_ITEM = new HashSet<PROGRAM_WEEK_DAY_ITEM>();
        this.STORAGE = new HashSet<STORAGE>();
        this.SHOW = new HashSet<SHOW>();
        this.ACTION = new HashSet<ACTION>();
    }

    public int ARTICLE_id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime date_created { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_modified { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string html { get; set; }
    public int WEB_USER_id { get; set; }
    public int ARTICLE_STATUS_id { get; set; }
    public int ARTICLE_CATEGORY_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_published { get; set; }
    public string preview_image { get; set; }

    //code generation tool added those navigation props
    public virtual ARTICLE_CATEGORY ARTICLE_CATEGORY { get; set; }
    public virtual ARTICLE_STATUS ARTICLE_STATUS { get; set; }
    public virtual WEB_USER WEB_USER { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PROGRAM_WEEK_DAY_ITEM> PROGRAM_WEEK_DAY_ITEM { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<STORAGE> STORAGE { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SHOW> SHOW { get; set; }

    //this one causes trouble I think, but no clue why
    public virtual ICollection<ACTION> ACTION { get; set; }
}
```

metadata class - just display names and formats:

```
public class ARTICLE_Metadata
{
    [Key]
    public int ARTICLE_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Vytvořeno")]
    public System.DateTime date_created { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Změněno")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_modified { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Publikováno")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_published { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Titulek článku")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Obsah článku")]
    [UIHint("tinymce_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string html { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Vytvořil")]
    public int WEB_USER_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public int ARTICLE_STATUS_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Kategorie")]
    public int ARTICLE_CATEGORY_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Náhledový obrázek")]
    public string preview_image { get; set; }
}
```

and finally form in razor view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Articles", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "base-form" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Nový článek</legend>

    @Html.DatePickerFor(model => model.date_published, false)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.WEB_USER_id)

    <p class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ARTICLE_STATUS_id)
        @Html.DropDownList("ARTICLE_STATUS_id")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ARTICLE_STATUS_id)
    </p>

    <p class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ARTICLE_CATEGORY_id)
        @Html.DropDownList("ARTICLE_CATEGORY_id")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ARTICLE_CATEGORY_id)
    </p>

    <p class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title)
    </p>

    <div class="html-editor">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.html)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Vytvořit" class="submit" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

When model validates and comes to controller action, ModelState.IsValid == false, ModelState claims error on property ACTION which is not even present in the table and not supposed to be there, it is navigation property.

Error has an exeption: **The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'namespace.ACTION' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.**

I tried to attach debugger view image but this web did not allowed it to me. I have other entities managed via controllers and view the same way - about 30 where this does not happen.

**How can I get rid of this problem without creating extra model with the same properties but without navigation ones?** Or just prevent this navigation property to be included to validation. Or it is a new microsoft nonsense feature?

Comment: As I am thinking, maybe it has to do with both side navigation properties. If I have foreign key in table ACTION -> ARTICLE, because it has a field ARTICLE_id. It adds navigation property ACTION.ARTICLE as many to one. But why it also adds a navigation property ARTICLE.ACTION as ICollection when it is not in direction of foreign key? Maybe exists some convention which would disable this.

Comment: There is probably a naming conflict with ACTION. The model binder is receiving a value for it so it's trying to apply it to the ARTICLE.ACTION property. You can try just pluralizing your ACTION property to ACTIONS.

Comment: It seems to work, did it not forget the renaming after next update of entity model from database? Beacuse it seems the table ACTION is somehow not cool name for a table :) Even controller for ACTION entity are making troubles, returns allways NULL. Someone from microsoft should reveal not recommended names for tables :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some times these weird errors in db-first comes from that the name of a navigation property in an entity, is same as the name of another entity. I myself experienced these problems sometimes, and I don't know exactly what is the reason.

Anyway, renaming that navigation property must get you rid of that weird error...

Comment: Yes, it did, dynamic binder seems not recognizing purpose as foreign key. It looks that even entity designer remembers renaming of navigation property, so far now problem solved :) The weird thing is that navigation property name is always name of another entity.  I would mark user Mufaka as question solver, but I can't because he wrote just a comment, so I'll mark you to prove that question is solved.